# Identify Features tool - selecting multiple features unless I really zoom in. Way to adjust selection radius

Tags: qgis, features, identify

Identify Features tool - it selects multiple features unless I really zoom in. Is there any way to adjust the "selection radius" of the Identify Features tool so its "point sharp". I want to keep the map zoomed out (to have many features shown) yet still be able to pinpoint a tiny feature, point and click on it, then have  my QT Designer UI pop up.

**Update**

Answer below was very helpful. Just wondering if the Identify Features Tool can go any "sharper" than 0 MM? Or can the Identify Features Tool icon be swapped out for cross hairs?

**Before the click:**

[image: before click]

**After the click**

[image: after click]

Two features are selected. I believe the arrow icon is is actually a rectangle. Ideally it would only be the tip of the arrow that was "hot". Or, any way to swap that tool out for a cross hair?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to define the search radius for identify:
(QGIS 2.14)
Settings >> Options >> Map Tools >> Identify

The default is 2,00 mm

Comment: The setting it to 0 works good for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using the Identify tool, you can right click to bring up a context menu which lists all features within the map tool's tolerance:

[image]

This way you can select a specific feature without having to change the map tool settings.

Comment: Thanks, very handy. Unfortunately the key column is just numbers so Right-click pop up doesn't yield useful information. I'm on a laptop because I have to do field work. A wheel (zoom) mouse might be better for quick zooming. (more at "update" above)

Comment: @rjlabs you can change the field displayed in the layer's properties